# What's the difference between ORDER BY and ORDER BY ASC

Tags: c#, mysql, performance, sorting

I've been using mysql for a while now at my internship, and I'm wondering if there's a difference between declaring if your **`ORDER BY`** is **`ASC`** or not declaring it.

```
var result = (from r in db.table1 orderby r.datetime select r)
```

and

```
var result = (from r in db.table1 orderby r.datetime ascending select r)
```

*note: both return the same result.*

I could imagine that a difference in performance would matter in large applications, when using a large database.

Comment: No difference, it's the same in most if not all rdbms like MySQL, Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, Teradata, SAP and others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `ORDER BY` is sorted in ascending order, so I guess there are no differences between your requests.

From [this documentation](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/order_by.php):

> ASC Optional -- 
>   It sorts the result set in ascending order by expression (**default, if no modifier is provider**).
>
> DESC Optional --
>   It sorts the result set in descending order by expression.

Answer (score 2):

I think `ORDER BY` AND `ORDER BY ASC` are the same

Answer (score 1):

None, as the default sorting order is `ascending`. So when you say `order by col` it's actually `order by col asc`. Unless otherwise you want to invert the sorting order, you need to mention the order explicitly saying `order by col desc`